# NameError: class is not defined when overriding a class in python

Tags: python, kivy, overriding, nameerror

Why can't python seem to find the `InterfaceWithNoMenu` class

```
class Settings(Screen):

        class SettingsWithNoMenu(kivy.uix.settings.SettingsWithNoMenu):

                def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                        self.interface_cls = InterfaceWithNoMenu
                        kivy.uix.settings.SettingsWithNoMenu.__init__( self, *args, **kwargs )

        class InterfaceWithNoMenu(kivy.uix.settings.ContentPanel):
                def add_widget(self, widget):
                        if self.container is not None and len(self.container.children) > 0:
                                raise Exception(
                                'ContentNoMenu cannot accept more than one settings panel')
                        super(InterfaceWithNoMenu, self).add_widget(widget)
                        kivy.uix.settings.InterfaceWithNoMenu.__init__( self, *args, **kwargs )

        actionview = ObjectProperty(None)
        settings_content = ObjectProperty(None)

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):

                super(Settings, self).__init__(**kwargs)
...
```

I'm trying to change the look/feel/behaviour of the [Settings module](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.settings.html) in a [kivy-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kivy_(framework)) python GUI app.

Unfortunately, when I create a settings window with the above program that creates an instance of the locally-overridden `self.SettingsWithNoMenu` class, I get the following error:

```
     self.interface_cls = InterfaceWithNoMenu
 NameError: name 'InterfaceWithNoMenu' is not defined
```

I don't understand. It's right there. I mean, the class `InterfaceWithNoMenu` is literally defined right underneath the one (`SettingsWithNoMenu`) that's referencing it.

Why can't the class `SettingsWithNoMenu` find `InterfaceWithNoMenu`? Why am I getting a `NameError` here?

Comment: Of course it isn't defined. **you can never access names in a class body from an enclosed scope**. This is why you can't call a method `foo` inside of another method `bar` by using `foo()`, you have to use `self.foo()`

Comment: so you can use `self.interface_cls = Settings.InterfaceWithNoMenu` Better yet, you should just *not nest these classes*, is that somethig `kivy` is forcing on you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga changing it to `Settings.InterfaceWithNoMenu` made the error go away :tada:

Comment: Yes, but again, what you really should be doing probably is simply not nesting these classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InterfaceWithNoMenu` is defined in the namespace of the `Settings` class, not the global or local namespace.  You should be able to do:

```
self.interface_cls = Settings.InterfaceWithNoMenu
```

since `Settings` is available in the global namespace.

Nested class definitions are a little awkward IMO and I would usually recommend not using them, especially if there's a dependency between "sibling" classes like this that requires the nested class to access its enclosing class.

Comment: I was nesting it so that I could explicitly say `self.SettingsWithNoMenu` when creating an instance from it. If the class has no parent class, then is there any way I can reference it "absolutely" to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield just put it at the module level and reference it as `SettingWithNoMenu`, that is totally unambiguous.

Comment: well, it's not ambiguous if I'm using `from kivy.uix.A import B` everywhere, as the kivy docs tell you to do. For example, `from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithNoMenu`

Comment: @MichaelAltfield but you are using `kivy.uix.settings.SettingsWithNoMenu` in your own code? That would be the best way. Or when you import this module you are writing, you just use `import mymodule` and `mymodule.SettingsWithNoMenu` and it is namespaced. No ambiguity.

Comment: Give your class a name that makes it unambiguous, like `MyAppNameSettingsWithNoMenu`.  Or import the kivy base class as its own name: `from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithNoMenu as SettingsWithNoMenuBase`.  (I'd prefer the first.)  Or leave the imported modules as their own namespaces instead of doing `import from`.  There are a lot of ways to do this and IMO nested classes are one of the more confusing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `InterfaceWithNoMenu` class before defining it, as you declare an instance of it in the `SettingWithNoMenu` class.

Can you swap those class definitions around and see if that fixes this error? (and you might need to make the reference more specific, with a self or a this or something)

Comment: it won't. that isn't the issue

Comment: I don't see how the order would matter here; the original source that I'm overriding has them defined in the same order https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/settings.py#L1140

Comment: @MichaelAltfield the order doesn't matter in this case, but from your link, you'll notice, **they don't nest the classes**. Why are you nesting?